# Magento 2 - how to reference a template of my theme in a layout file?

Tags: magento2, layout, theme, template, magento2.3.2

I have this file

> *app\design\frontend\company\mytheme\web\templates\header\foobar.phtml*

How can I reference it in a layout file e.g. in

> *app\design\frontend\company\mytheme\Magento_Theme\layout\default.xml*

e.g. to set it as a template for a block?

```
<referenceContainer name="header.container">
    <container name="header-wrapper" label="Page Header" as="header-wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="header content foobar">
        <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo"
               name="logo" 
               template="Magento_Theme::foobar.phtml"  <-- this does not work... how to make it right and set foobar.phtml as template ?
        >
            <arguments>
                <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">189</argument>
                <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">64</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

If I move **foobar.phtml** to `app\design\frontend\company\mytheme\Magento_Theme\templates` then it works, but how does it work from my themes web directory?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by creating a new folder named **Company_Mytheme** (Vendor_Themename) and moving `foobar.phtml` to

> app\design\frontend\company\mytheme\Company_Mytheme\templates\foobar.phtml

Then I referenced it like this:

```
<referenceContainer name="header.container">
    <container name="header-wrapper" label="Page Header" as="header-wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="header content foobar">
        <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo"
               name="logo" 
               template="Company_Mytheme::foobar.phtml"
        >
            <arguments>
                <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">189</argument>
                <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">64</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

You can name the folder anything you like, e.g. **Foo_Bar**, it will also work, you just have to make sure to use it in the layout